# Change the font of specific words in cells

Tags: vba

I am trying to change the font of specific words in a range of Cells. So in the Range of A2:Q1000, if the word `Risk` or `High` is in the cell, the font should change to red and be bold. Below is the code I put together so far.

```
Sub Font_Change()

Dim dData As Range
Dim Name As String

Set dData = Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A2:Q10000")

For Each Cell In dData
    If Cell = "Risk" Then
        Cell.Font.Color = 2
        Cell.Font.Bold = True
    ElseIf Cell = "Medium" Then
        Cell.Font.Bold
    ElseIf Cell = "Hign" Then
        Cell.Font.Color = 2
        Cell.Font.Bold = True
    End If
Next

End Sub
```

Comment: What is your problem?

Comment: You've got a typo - Hign instead of High

Answer (score 0):

Your code is pretty close!

It could be coded another way that is easier to manage but will get the same results

```
Sub Font_Change()

     Dim dData As Range
     Dim Name As String
     Dim cell As Variant

     Set dData = Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A2:Q10000")

     For Each cell In dData
         With cell
             Select Case cell.Value
                 Case "Risk", "High"
                     .Font.Color = 2
                     .Font.Bold = True
                 Case "Medium"
                     .Font.Bold
             End Select
         End With
     Next cell
End Sub
```

For Case statements combined with Like statements it is coded a bit differently (i.e. `Like "*Risk*"` ):
I've incorporated the word case override as described in @dasg7's answer `UCase(str1)` as well as a different way to accomplish the same `InStr(str1, str2) > 0`:

```
Option Compare Text    
Sub Font_Change()

     Dim dData As Range
     Dim Name As String
     Dim cell As Variant

     Set dData = Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A2:Q10000")

     For Each cell In dData
         With cell
             Select Case True
                 Case UCase(cell.value) like "*RISK*" or UCase(cell.value) like "*HIGH*"
                     .Font.Color = vbRed
                     .Font.Bold = True
                 Case InStr(cell.Value, "medium") > 0
                     .Font.Color = vbYellow
                     .Font.Bold = True
                 Case Else
                     .Font.Color = vbBlack
                     .Font.Bold = False
             End Select
         End With
     Next cell
End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you Kevin Conner and dasg7.

Comment: How would I adjust the code to select the case even if its not an exact match. So if the work "Risk" along with other words are in the cell?

Comment: @Tony. I've updated my answer to include similar cells in addition to exact cells.

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:

```
Sub tests()

For Each cell In Range("A2:Q1000")

If UCase(cell.Value) Like "*RISK*" Or UCase(cell.Value) Like "*HIGH*" Then
cell.Font.Color = vbRed
cell.Font.Bold = True
End If
If UCase(cell.Value) Like "*MEDIUM*" then cell.Font.Color = vbRed
Next cell

End Sub
```